# Rails sort with custom method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting

I have a large set of `@clients` that I'd like to sort by the client's last name but I cannot seem to get it working.  I need to `select` `:name` and `:id` to speed up the query.

```
@clients = Client.all.select(:name, :id)

@clients.sort { |a, b| a.name && b.name ? a.name.split(" ").last[0] <=> b.name.split(" ").last[0] : a ? -1 : 1}
```

The result I get is:

```
#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Client id: 460, name: "Jim Jimmy">, #<Client id: 440, name: nil>, #<Client id: 231, name: "Paigetest Doyle">, #<Client id: 441, name: "Jeremy Lopez">, #<Client id: 462, name: "blah blah">, #<Client id: 348, name: "Jan Aldrich">, #<Client id: 464, name: "fefw fewfew">, #<Client id: 466, name: nil>, #<Client id: 67, name: "Jeremy Lopez">, #<Client id: 449, name: nil>, ...]>
```

Comment: what error do you get ? what result do you get?

Comment: You should let the database do the sorting by using `order`. Don't use `sort` on an ActiveRecord::Relation—especially if speed is a concern. Also: http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: But the last name is not a column on the table.  I need to calculate it as I loop

Comment: what database are you using?

Comment: I am using Postgres

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a [cool feature called `split_part`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html) in `Postgres` that allows to split a string and get the word on specified position.

I believe the `last_name` is on the second position, hence `SQL` syntax will look something like this.

```
SELECT *, split_part(name, ' ', 2) AS last_name FROM clients ORDER BY last_name;
```

`ActiveRecord` syntax is going to look like:

```
Client.select("id, name, split_part(name, ' ', 2) as last_name").order("last_name")
```

I have no access to your env, so here can be some mistakes, but I wanted to make sure you got the idea.

Hope it helps.

Comment: You missed `select` double quotes: `select("id, name, split_part(name, ' ', 2) as last_name")`.

Comment: Thanks for the note

Comment: Beautiful.  I modified slightly to get rid of case based sorting: `Client.select("id, name, split_part(LOWER(name), ' ', 2) as last_name").order("last_name")`.  I think this response will be helpful to many, I'm not sure why all the downvotes?